# vb.net messagebox click behaves different to enter key

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

net gurus

I have the following piece of code. If I mouse click on the messagebox OK button the code behaves correctly but if I press enter it sets focus back to txtusename but then jumps to txtpassword. Any ideas why?

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text) Then
        Dim msgResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("User Name required", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        If msgResult = DialogResult.OK Then
            txtUserName.Focus()
        End If
        Return

    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text) Then
        Dim msgResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Password required", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        'MsgBox("Password required", vbOKOnly, vbExclamation)
        txtUserName.Select()
        txtPassword.Select()

        Return
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

In case there is a value on `txtUserName` and the `txtPassword` is null or empty you show a `MessageBox`. After showing the `MessageBox` (no matter the user selected) you select the `txtUserName` and `txtPassword`. Since you can only select one `TextBox`, the `txtPassword` is finally selected.

On the `Form` the `txtUserName` is selected first, so the cursor jumps from `txtPassword` to `txtUserName`. At the end the `txtPassword` is selected so the cursor jumps now from `txtUserName` to `txtPassword`.

You also using `.Select` on the `ElseIf` part. In case you want to set the cursor to the `TextBox` you need to use `.Focus` (like on the `If` part).

You need to remove the `txtUserName.Select()` on the `ElseIf` and using `.Focus` instead of `.Select` on `txtPassword` to solve your issue:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserName.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("User Name required", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        txtUserName.Focus()
        Return
    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password required", "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        txtPassword.Focus()
        Return
    End If

    'more code for database connection.
End Sub
```

Comment: `If msgResult = DialogResult.OK Then...` is useless. The result will always be `OK` as the MessageBox only has the OK-button. And `Return` is useless too, as long as there's no code between the last `End If` and `End Sub`.

Comment: @MatSnow - Yes the `If` is useless. Removed.

Comment: @MatSnow There is more code which establishes the connection to the sql server so I need to exit the sub if either textbox has not been populated

Comment: @Sebastian Brosch I realize the txtpassword portion is jumbled but I had changed the code several times trying to fathom out why a messagebox click on the OK button behaves one way but pressing enter behaves differently. When I mouse click the OK button the code catching an empty txtusername processes correctly returning focus to the txtusername textbox but if I press the enter key instead it returns focus to the txtusername textbox then automatically the focus moves to the next tab order control which is the txtpassword textbox.

Comment: @Sebastian Brosch Why that difference in behaviour is my question & then how do I remedy it so it returns focus to the correct textbox without moving focus on again

Comment: Well my question is not answered yet it's been marked as answered which is misleading to others & I'm too new to be able to change the status

Comment: @HughSelfTaught - the above should work the same way with click or key press. maybe there are some more events (`btnOK.Key...`)?

Comment: @HughSelfTaught - *yet it's been marked as answered which is misleading to others* - It is not marked as answered. A green tick marks a answer as accepted answer. Actually the answer is upvoted once.

Comment: connString = CreateConnectionString()
        Try
            Using conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString)
                conn.Open()
                gblConn = connString
                frmMainMenu.ShowDialog()
                Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

Comment: @SebatianBrosch above comment is the code after the messagebox before end sub